# Building a framework in C# Want to be able to save objects into database

Tags: c#

This is more a question of design / best practice than anything else. Technical solutions are appreciated but I'm thinking more of methodology.

I'm building a .net framework. This framework is meant to be used for a variety of applications that may store data in different ways (SQL, MySql, Oracle, File System, Etc)

The purpose of the framework is to handle specific business logic and interactions.

I'd like the framework to be able to save it's various objects however the user wants for later retrieval, but I don't want to bind users to ONLY using the storage solution I use (Enterprise SQL Server)

Should I just let the person using the framework figure out how to store the data? or should I try and build in some sort of SaveTo / LoadFrom methods that would save to a database based on parameters passed in?

Should I build a save method that must be overriden?

Should I build an additional namespace / framework for each data storage solution?

What would you consider to be best practice?

Comment: People already built these frameworks for you. They are called ORM's. :)

Comment: Check if any of the following tools suit your needs: Entity Framework, NHibernate, Dapper, PetaPoco, etc

Comment: @CaptainRedbelly - Can you pick only one of those questions you want answers to?  The overal question you have seems better suited at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ since its just a general programming question.

Comment: @Srini is right, you should use an existing ORM tool for that. Your best bet is probably using [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other already pointed out, at this maturity stage of C# it doesn't make a lot of sense building something that complex having a lot of excellent and free tools at hand.

You probably should research a little on internet about existing ORM and check if any of those are suitable for your requirements, if not, you may be able to flexibilize your requeriements to avoid having to create something from scratch :)

The only valid reason would be personal research objectives, but even in this case, you should take a look to existing frameworks to get best practices from years of evolution.

Some links for a starting:

- [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) definition (Wikipedia)
- [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/): mature, open source object-relational mapper for the .NET framework
- [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx): Microsoft’s recommended data access technology for new applications

Comment: research a little is being kind. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> This is more a question of design / best practice than anything else. Technical solutions are appreciated but I'm thinking more of methodology.
>   I'm building a .net framework. This framework is meant to be used for a variety of applications that may store data in different ways

**A framework, best practices and methodologies mentioned in the first paragraph. Wow!**

I assume you are planning a sizable journey, are belted up and have a helmet on. :-)
I can highly recommend:

A good book on how to write frameworks:  [Framework Guidelines](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/microsoft-dotnet/9780321545671)

How to tackle Design and complexity [Domain-Driven Design](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0-321-12521-5)
Arguably the best practice still.

If you choose EF as your ORM (i did) Julie Lerman has excellent guides on this topic

[Programming Entity Framework: Code First](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449317867)
[Programming Entity Framework: DbContext](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781449331825)

If required: OO principles strategies and Design patterns
Such as  [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/patterns/0201633612)
By if you are familar with SOLID Principles of Object Oriented Design. Then skip.
Not all devs are. So keep and eye on this if not working alone.

Once you have got into deep framework design, you will want to use libraries for many tasks.

Just 1 example of dozens would be an Inversion of Control tool, A logging tool and exception handling tool.  An example is the Microsoft Enterprise Library

Look for a Enterprise Library 6 book,
[Enterprise Library 6 docu and code download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx)

The list goes on when you introduce various UI technologies and approaches.
The programming language of choice is assumed mastered. You said .net so i assumed C#

What about communication / messaging in and out of the system?
Rest Services ? SOAP ?   Use WCF or not... 
ASP.NET options and approaches...  A lot of read in this space to be done
What UI technology and platforms. Another iceberg

Very important is SECURITY
I started here as a solution that isnt secure is useless
research **Identity and Access Contro**l in ASP.NET 4.5
and **.NET Distributed Systems Architecture and security**

You should also consider your approach to testing.
Plan this early.  Are you going to do TDD.   What test tool will you use.

Software Control ?  SVN or TFS   version control will be important on any framework application.

If you are serious about learning , take a look at PluralSight on demand video site.
It is a "relatively cheap" subscription service.  I found it very useful.

good Luck